# Returning HTML elements from a view in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to return an image from a view to a template in Django. Currently my view has an array I want to display in a table, but in different ways (most elements as strings but one in particular as an image)

```
items = [
  ['an apple', '<img src="apple.png" \\>'], 
  ['a pear', '<img src="pear.png" \\>'], 
  ['an orange', <img src="orange.png" \\>]
]
```

and in my template,

```
<table>
{% for fruit in items %}
  <tr>
  {% for element in fruit %}
    <td>
      {{ element }}
    </td>
  {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

This prints out the literal string  instead of displaying the image pear.png.

Is there a way I can tell the template to insert the element into the code rather than render as a string?

Comment: Can you somehow change the data structure to not include the img tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The filter `safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) marks a string as not requiring further HTML escaping prior to output.

```
<table>
{% for fruit in items %}
  <tr>
  {% for element in fruit %}
    <td>
      {{ element | safe }}
    </td>
  {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

---

*Sidenote:* You can also convert your items structure to a dict for easier and clearer usage:

```
items = {
  'an apple': '<img src="apple.png" />', 
  'a pear': '<img src="pear.png" />', 
  'an orange': '<img src="orange.png" />'
}
```

Template:

```
<table>
{% for fruit, img in items.items %}
  <tr>
    <td> {{ fruit }}
    <td> {{ img | safe }} </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

---

Lastly, you can also only add the image source in your dict and avoid having to use `safe`:

```
items = {
  'an apple': 'apple.png', 
  'a pear': 'pear.png', 
  'an orange': 'orange.png'
}
```

Template:

```
<table>
{% for fruit, img in items.items %}
  <tr>
    <td> {{ fruit }}
    <td> <img src="{{ img }}" /> </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, safe was exactly what I was looking for! I initially thought about using the src={{ img }} but because i'm not sure how many cells there will be everytime I had to do it programmatically

Answer (score 0):

```
 {% for fruit, image_tag in items %}
     <td> {{fruit}} </td>
     <td> {{image_tag|safe}} </td>
    {% endfor %}
```

you need to mark the string as safe for the xss protection https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/#automatic-html-escaping

> If you don’t want data to be auto-escaped, on a per-site, per-template
>   level or per-variable level, you can turn it off in several ways.
>
> Why would you want to turn it off? Because sometimes, template
>   variables contain data that you intend to be rendered as raw HTML, in
>   which case you don’t want their contents to be escaped. For example,
>   you might store a blob of HTML in your database and want to embed that
>   directly into your template. Or, you might be using Django’s template
>   system to produce text that is not HTML – like an email message, for
>   instance. For individual variables¶
>
> To disable auto-escaping for an individual variable, use the safe
>   filter:
>
> This will be escaped: {{ data }} This will not be escaped: {{
>   data|safe }}

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
{% for fruit, fruitimage in items %}
 <td> {{fruit}} </td>
 <td> <img src="{{fruitimage}}"> </td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This duplicates the image tag which is an invalid source